# Undefined variable: query error//

Tags: php

I tried to solve this problem on my own but I'm stucked. I work on blog site with php and I encounter an error where i want to add a comment in an article :

Undefined variable: query in C:\wamp\www\entertheletter.dev\fonctions\blog.php on line 73

I don't unterstand where it doesn't work. It happen when I click on the submit button. Here my code :

the function where Php indicates an error:

```
function recherche(){
            global $bdd;

            extract($_POST);

            $recherche = $bdd->prepare("SELECT id, titre, accroche, publication, image FROM articles WHERE titre LIKE :query OR contenu LIKE :query ORDER by id DESC");
            $recherche->execute([ 
                "query" => '%' . $query . '%' 

            ]); 
            $recherche = $recherche->fetchAll();

            return $recherche;
        }
```

the function to comment :

```
function commenter() { 
           if(isset($_SESSION["membre"])) {
                global $bdd;

            $erreur = "";

            extract($_POST);

            if(!empty($commentaire)) {
                $id_article = (int)$_GET["id"];

                $commenter = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO commentaires(id_membre, id_article, commentaire) VALUES(:id_membre, :id_article, :commentaire)");
                $commenter->execute([
                    "id_membre" => $_SESSION["membre"],
                    "id_article" => $id_article,
                    "commentaire" => nl2br(htmlentities($commentaire))
                    ]);    

                }
               else
                    $erreur .= "Vous devez écrire du texte";

               return $erreur;
            }

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: what's in Line 73?

Comment: "query" => '%' . $query . '%'

Comment: is `$query` comes from `$_POST`? if so, check `$_POST` has `$_POST['query']`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use `extract` for `$_POST` or `$_GET` because if keys are not present in `$_POST` then PHP will throw an undefined error. Also, you need to check whether data in `$_POST` is exist or not.

Instead of using `extract($_POST)`  use `$_POST` directly,

```
function recherche(){
    global $bdd;

    if(isset($_POST['query'])){

        $recherche = $bdd->prepare("SELECT id, titre, accroche, publication, image FROM articles WHERE titre LIKE :query OR contenu LIKE :query ORDER by id DESC");
        $recherche->execute([ 
            "query" => '%' . $query . '%' 

        ]); 
        $recherche = $recherche->fetchAll();

        return $recherche;
    }
}
```